# single line cmd sed Mac OSX el capitan

Tags: bash, macos, sed

I'm trying to **single line** the following **working** command to run it in a bash:

```
LANG=C sed -E '
s/$/\\z/ 
:while
s/([0-9]{6})(.*\\z.*)/\2 "\1"/
twhile
s/.*\\z//' myfile.txt
```

sample for myfile.txt :

> 123456 \r\n  \r\n  789112 \r\n  889667

output of the above cmd (which is the expected result) :

> "123456" "789112" "889667"

neither this :

```
LANG=C sed -E 's/$/\\z/; :while; s/([0-9]{6})(.*\\z.*)/\2 "\1"/; twhile; s/.*\\z//' myfile.txt
```

output:

> 123456 \r\n  \r\n  789112 \r\n  889667\z

or this actually works:

```
LANG=C sed -E 's/$/\\z/' -E :while -E 's/([0-9]{6})(.*\\z.*)/\2 "\1"/;twhile' -E  's/.*\\z//' myfile.txt
```

output :

> sed: -E: No such file or directory
>
> sed: :while: No such file or directory
>
> sed: -E: No such file or directory
>
> sed: s/([0-9]{6})(.*\z.*)/\2 "\1"/;twhile: No such file or directory
>
> sed: -E: No such file or directory
>
> sed: s/.*\z//: No such file or directory
>
> 123456 \r\n  \r\n  789112 \r\n  889667\z

As a result, both display the one and only line of the file instead of multiple instance of the pattern /[0-9]{6}/

I believe that I'm missing something about how to use semicolon..

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Both display the one and only line of the file instead of multiple instance of the pattern /[0-9]{6}/. Missed this point in the post, thank you ;)

Comment: Can you provide sample input and output?

Comment: Sed complained about "unbalanced parenthesis" when I tried to run your working example.

Comment: @teppic That's because there is a missing `)` in the sub, i assumed it was a typo as they said it works.

Comment: Mac OS X means (old) BSD sed, so freaky rules about label names -- semicolons don't end them. Try `LANG=C sed -E -e 's/$/\\z/;:while' -e 's/([0-9]{6})(.*\\z.*)/\2 "\1"/;twhile' -e  's/.*\\z//' myfile.txt` (I would test it but I don't have a BSD at hand).

Comment: @Wintermute that works ! Thank you !! Could you explain me why... And  is there any way to write is in one expression (I'm just curious)

Comment: Labels are terminated by a literal newline, so the first label is everything after the `:while`. You could insert a newline escape after the `:while` and `:twhile`, e.g. `:while'$'\n''s/...`, but it's a bashism. Using multiple `-e` flags is cleaner, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sed is for simple substitutions on individual lines, that is all. What you are trying to do is not that so you should not be trying to use sed to do it. It's not clear what you ARE trying to do but is this it:

```
$ awk -v RS='\\s+' 'NF{print "\"" $0 "\""}' file
"123456"
"789112"
"889667"
```

That uses GNU awk for multi-char RS and the `\s` shorthand for `[[:space:]]`. The above was run on this input file:

```
$ cat -v file
123456 ^M
 ^M
 789112 ^M
 889667
```

Which is what I think you're trying to express with your posted sample input:

```
$ printf '123456 \r\n \r\n 789112 \r\n 889667' |
    awk -v RS='\\s+' 'NF{print "\"" $0 "\""}'
"123456"
"789112"
"889667"
```

or if you prefer to look for matching strings rather than the spaces that separate the strings:

```
$ printf '123456 \r\n \r\n 789112 \r\n 889667' |
    awk -v RS='[0-9]{6}' '{print "\"" RT "\""}'
"123456"
"789112"
"889667"
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. My file is a single line that really looks like this `123456 \r\n<some text> \r\n 789112 <some text>\r\n<some there> 889667`. I started with awk but couldn't figure out the right way to do it, so I tried sed... But it seems that I'm wrong about what tool to use between sed and awk...

Comment: But by definition if it contains `\r\n` is is NOT a single line since lines end with `\r\n` on Windows and `\n` on UNIX so either way there are newlines present. Unless you mean it literally contains the 4 characters `backslash r backslash n`.

Comment: The line is an answer of a curl request to a server, and the server responds is a json with \r\n values in it (which is stupid... but I don't have any control on it, I just try to parse the answer...)

Comment: that's all fine, but if it contains `\r\n`s it is NOT a single line by any Windows or UNIX definition.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I didn't mean to get you confused... Thank you a lot for your help :) !